# How can expand the functions of my key fob?

Tags: nissan, electronics, maxima, fob, reprogram

I want to reprogram they intelligent key (i-key) for my 2014 Nissan Maxima to do more stuff.

When I press and hold the unlock button on the i-key, the two front windows open. I want to make all 4 windows open.

Also I want to make the car lights turn on when the key is close to the car

Also I have a horn button in my i-key. When I press and hold on it, I want the engine to turn on rather than the horn if possible.

I am asking because I am not sure if that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to do it yourself, but companies such as [KP Technologies](http://www.kptechnologies.com/products.php) make modules to do almost all of the functions you would like to use.

Note: I am in no way affiliated with this company, nor have I ever tried their product, but I have seen them mentioned on various forums.

Comment: Usually all these functions are controlled by the body control module and if you can't set them through the cars setup menu than you need a factory scantool to setup features.